# i have an issue with cURL in 2 sites

Tags: php, curl, drupal, module, libcurl

I have 2 `drupal` sites installed in different machines..On the first one,on status report in the list I have:

```
cURL    cURL library Enabled
```

only that row with cURL...On the second `drupal` site, I have that:

```
cURL    cURL library Enabled

cURL    Enabled
```

> On the second file my module uses the `cURL` perfect while on the first I cannot use the `cURL`....

Could you tell why you think is this happening? And how I can correct that issue??

Comment: have you checked the installations and module enabled status correctly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It may be because curl lib not exist on server. You can try installed curl on machine or no. It possible from terminal or just create test.php with code:

```
// Check if curl module installed
if(!function_exists('curl_init')) {
    throw new Exception("cURL module not installed.");
}

phpinfo();
```

If curl lib exist but not enable check php.ini on row ';extension=php_curl.dll'. Remove character ';' and restart server. I think problem in settings php.

Comment: I opened that file /etc/php5/apache2/php.ini but it does not have a line with extension=php_curl.dll i search with Ctrl+w and nothing found..

Comment: Try to add extension=php_curl.dll in file. In my config is below default_socket_timeout. And make sure that works /etc/php5/apache2/php.ini. You can print path to php.ini in test.php.